# I'm not understanding the algebra behind rearranging this equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

[This is the original question from Paul's Online Math Notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpHZZ.png)

I'm having trouble seeing exactly how the algebra in his solution works, my algebra is dodgy at times and I do plan to work on it, but if someone could write a quick proof/more detailed solution that would be great!

[This is the solution to the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EyO9.png)

[Here is another similar situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lGVj.png)

Comment: sorry i can not read the whole equation

Comment: is it $14 e^{6-x}+e^{12x-7}=0$ ? Besides, why don't you type it ?

Answer (score 1):

So, you have the equation :

$$14e^{6-x} + e^{12x-7}=0$$

Let's gather the exponential stuff on one side while leaving the constant $14$ at the other one :

$$14e^{6-x}=-e^{12x-7} \Leftrightarrow-\frac{e^{12x-7}}{e^{6-x}}=14$$

By applying exponential operation rules (power rules), we get :

$$-\frac{e^{12x-7}}{e^{6-x}}=14 \Leftrightarrow -e^{12x-7-(6-x)}=14 \Leftrightarrow -e^{13x-13}=14$$

Now, to solve this equation, one would just apply the natural logarithm function $\ln$ on both sides, since it's $"1-1"$ **but be careful**. The RHS is negative (which means you **cannot** apply the logarithm function and the LHS is positive, which means that this equation is **not possible**, thus meaning it has no solution.

Comment: You lost the negative sign. The equation has no solution. One can see that immediatly, since you add two positive numbers.

Answer (score 0):

we have $$14e^{6-x}+e^{12x-7}=0$$ then we can write
$$14e^{6-x}=-e^{12x-7}$$ and after dividing by $$e^{6-x}$$ we get
$$14=-\frac{e^{12x-7}}{e^{6-x}}$$ and now use that $$\frac{a^n}{a^{m}}=a^{n-m}$$